# "Leaks Discovered" but not shown in detail via Instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, memory-leaks, instruments

I am attempting to obtain information on possible leaks that exist in the iPad app I am currently developing. Typically when Instruments finds a leak, a red 'peak' appears on the graph within the leaks section and I am able to obtain information on that leak within my code. Currently, Instruments is instead telling me "Leaks Discovered", but there are no peaks on the leaks graph and no details are shown. Any idea on why that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure unless there's more information but I generally use "Build and Analyze" and fix all the leaks it shows there and only then move on to Instruments. Try Build and Analyze to see if it shows any leaks there. If you're using Xcode 4, its just Analyze under Product.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already built and analyzed the code and don't see anything on that end...